# How can I fix python code to match cluster of dots from scatter with kernel density probability countour plot using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, subplot, kernel-density

Dear python specialists,

I am trying to plot a 2D scatter plot for two variables phi2 and theta on the top of their Kernel PDF countour.
When I do that there are two main maximum for the Kernel but there three main clusters of points. How can I fix my code to get a plot that makes more sense having for each cluster of datapoints a maximum for the kernel density probability?

Thanks in advance,
Cheers,
Lazaro

```
from scipy.stats import circvar
from scipy.stats import circmean
import scipy.stats as st
from matplotlib import ticker, cm
from matplotlib.transforms import Bbox
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable, axes_size
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter
from matplotlib import ticker as tick

# phi2 is this:
#array([  73.62324995,  122.64334345,   72.67064757, -175.63713227,
       #-176.42631705,  111.97090782,  112.43262405,  113.1094183 ,
        #111.53501099,  110.69594668,  -75.46326239,  -67.76160179,
        #-95.94455459,  -64.01216275,  -93.67976318,   12.22483834,
         #11.24380368,    7.12787335,    8.57004673,    9.57479941])

# theta is this:
#array([161.96978904, 174.70995924, 159.42606079, 174.98472276,
       #174.94378114, 167.49406671, 167.38426198, 164.57103987,
       #164.51372335, 164.46138757,  22.65628947,  13.59729108,
        #27.54987277,  16.46934502,  28.45572831,   4.02895771,
         #3.79725376,   3.9735054 ,   3.62785328,   3.48080227])

# Peform the kernel density estimate
xx, yy = np.mgrid[-180:180:((N+2) * 1j), 0:180:(N+2 * 1j)]
x, y = np.meshgrid(phi2, theta)
positions = np.vstack([xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
new_pos = np.vstack([x.ravel(), y.ravel()])
values = np.vstack([phi2, theta])
kernel = st.gaussian_kde(values)
f = np.reshape(kernel(positions).T, xx.shape)
ff = np.reshape(kernel(new_pos).T, x.shape)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Contourf plot
levels = np.linspace(f.min(), f.max(), 20)
#cfset = ax.contourf(xx, yy, f, levels = levels, cmap = plt.cm.jet, zorder=0)
#cfset = ax.contourf(xx, yy, f, levels = levels, cmap = 'viridis', zorder=0)
cfset = ax.contourf(xx, yy, f, levels = levels, zorder=0)
    
# Add scatter plot
scatter = ax.scatter(phi2, theta, color="red", linewidth=1, edgecolor="black", s=60, marker='x')
     
ax.set_xlim([-180, 180])                                                                           
ax.set_ylim([0, 180]) 
plt.show()
```

Comment: Maybe you could try seaborn?  `sns.kdeplot(x=phi2, y=theta, ax=ax)` and `sns.scatterplot(x=phi2, y=theta, ax=ax)`.  As a minimum, you can compare that result with your own to get an idea where things might be wrong.

Comment: hey JohanC. With seaborn I get exactly the same thing. Why would the kernel density probability give two maximums instead of three? Not sure

Comment: The height of the kde depends on the number of points around each top.  The probability of being close to one of the higher tops is higher than the probability of being close to the third top.  That's part of how a pdf and a kde are defined. Maybe it looks more logical when you look at a 1D plot? `g = sns.jointplot(x=phi2, y=theta, kind='kde', fill=True); sns.scatterplot(x=phi2, y=theta, color='r', ax=g.ax_joint)`